# deleting rows from huge table SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

Helo,

I have a huge table T (approx  10^10 records) 
T.id is a primary key

When i try:

```
delete from T where id in (1,2,3....)
```

it works fast (about 50s for 10000 records)

When i try to use equivalent query:

```
delete from T where id < 10000
```

it works very long (over 1 hour !!!!)

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Use the faster option.

Comment: Please post the query execution plans, I suspect you have a table scan vs index lookup

Comment: If T.id is the Primary Key I'd expect it to be 'more or less as fast' as the IN (1, 2, 3, .. 9999) approach (CLUSTERED or not). Could it be your statistics are (way) out of date and the system simply didn't expect that many rows with id < 10000. Have a look at the (estimated) query plans and compare 'Expected rowcount' with 'actual rowcount'.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix both by using:

```
delete from T where id in (select id from T where id < 10000)
```

Comment: The question is WHY ?
Maybe the database spents a lot time  rebuiding the  index ?
Maybe if I use IN() , rebuilding the index occurs after all records deleting?
Is someone really knows?

Answer (score 0):

I think an alternative approach could be to copy the rows you want to keep to another table. In lot's of cases, sopying data is way faster than deleting data. So even if you want to keep 90%, this may still be the faster option.

I think it's worth a test at least.

Good luck!

Comment: I think about it, but there is another table T2 with ForeignKey to T.

Comment: If you know what you're doing, you can (temporarily) drop the FK, do all the work and then restore the FK. In fact, the FK might be slowing down your delete (if there is a lot to be deleted). That said, restoring the FK might take a while too, especially on a table with that many rows!

Answer (score -1):

If you delete huge no of record from Table it may cause Deadlock.Best    way of deleting huge record is Take year and Month of Date column for    EG:

```
DELETE from Table WHERE  id in (1,2,3....) AND YEAR(Date)=2018 AND Month(Date)=1
```

Comment: There is no problem with :
where id in (...)
The problem occurs when I use :
where id < 1000
I do not understand why
And additionally, I have no index on DATE field,

Comment: That doesn't even make sense!!?

Comment: @deroby well well Suppose you have a table which consist of 50 million records how will you delete during business hrs

Comment: I'd probably want to delete those outside of business hours. Anyway, the part that makes no sense here is that if you already know the PK fields, why would I want to add other fields to my `wHERE` clause? You want to delete in smaller chunks? Then limit the amount of id's; don't start involving other fields.